# Buttons sometimes doesn't get disabled on windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, button, user-controls

I have a windows form application, and I have UserControl that has some groupboxes and some buttons that should be enabled or disabled based on the user role,  like this:

```
this.btnEditArchive.Enabled = (ActiveUser.Instance.role == DConstants.kAdmin || ActiveUser.Instance.role == DConstants.kSuperAdmin);
```

This is placed in _Load event. Now sometimes when I switch between pages,
these buttons doesn't look disabled. But when I try to touch them, then become disabled. Seems like the UI somehow is not correctly drawn. How to fix this? What may be the cause of this?

Comment: It completely depends to the implementations. What do you mean by switching between pages? How do you do switching? Who is the owner of `Load` event, the control? the forms?

Comment: The question in the current format (and the answer as well) is not useful for future readers. Please edit the question and add more details. Take a look at [ASK].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be wrong, but according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms), `_Load` event happens only once, when the Form is first called. Maybe putting that code of yours into `_Activated` event will do the trick?

**EDIT**

I got confused as to what the answer was, but the principle is the same: `_Load` event only occurs once, when it is called for the first time. So, if you need to have something updated whenever you switch between them, put your code into `_VisibleChanged` event.

Comment: I got confused, sorry. But after doing some research, UserControl has the same description for `_Load` event: "Occurs before the control becomes visible for **the first time**". Maybe that's the problem? What if you put the code into `_VisibleChanged` event?

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra If something about the answer is wrong and you fixed it in the comments, it's better to edit the answer and reflect that change in the answer as well, to make the answer more relevant and more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand clearly but try this

```
this.Refresh();
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't help. As I said, when I click on one of the buttons (there are 3 of them) they all get disabled as it should be.